# Detect Faces in video, crop them and save all frames in the same order - opencv python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I'm reading a video file of a split-screen that was recorded in zoom. That video now has 2 faces from 2 streams. It should in the future work with as many streams as needed. 
I managed to detect the faces and crop them and save each as a different pic. 
However I try to number the face in each frame and was hoping that the person 0 would remain 0 through all frames, however it changes from frame to frame. some times the person on the left is 0 and the other one is 1 and sometimes vice versa.
As you will see, I just need 1 fps.

My code is as follows

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')


vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('facing the screen.mp4')
success, image = vidcap.read()
count = 0
sec = 0
try:
    if not os.path.exists('all_frames'):
        os.makedirs('all_frames')
except OSError:
    print('Error: Creating directory of data')
while success:
    time = round(vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC),0)
    fps = round(vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS),0)-1
if count % fps < 1:
    gimg = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # gimg = np.array(gimg, dtype='uint8')
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(image, scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighbors=5)
    f=0
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        crop_face = gimg[y-10:y + h+10, x-10:x + w +10]

        cv2.imwrite("./all_frames/frame%dPerson%d.jpg" % (count,f), crop_face)  # save frame as JPEG file
        # cv2.imshow("cropped", crop_face)
        print('Read a new frame: ', count, f, success, time, fps)
        f += 1


success, image = vidcap.read()

count += 1


vidcap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Any suggestions? Is my problem with numbering the same person consistently with the same number is clear?

Comment: I think the problem here might be that the classifier can not always classify the faces correctly. So sometimes it detects one person as another and vice versa.
Then you are facing the issue to improve the performance of the classifier. 

How have you trained the classifier? Perhaps you can make some improvements there.

Comment: I'm using an existing classifier. However, I don't need it to recognize the person, but rather use the xy coordinates for the order. I would assume that the x,y,w,h in faces would go from small to big. but now I realize that perhaps I should reorder the faces array first by x and then by y if possible. or by the combination of the sum of x and y - this way it would work as well with split-screen of a dozen faces.
Gave me an idea. Should go check how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the returned result by the classifier is in the regular form of x,y,w,h, I took the frame with most faces recognized, saved the coordinates as the base reference, and for each face recognized later I used the measured Euclidean distance of its x,y coordinates from the x,y coordinates of the base face. The ordered number of the face as was stored in the base reference is used to store and refer to the new recognized face. 
Note that according to the code as it is now, the first 30 seconds are used only to find the max faces recognized. Thus the rest of the code continues from sec 31 of the video. (start reading from the start or write that part of the code into the main process loop)

This solution doesn't come to provide an efficient code as I will work on that later, but rather to provide the logic of performing analyses on different faces in a video while increasing the likelihood of constantly referring to the same face throughout the entire analysis of the video.

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
# import tensorflow as tf

def dist(x1,x2,y1,y2):
    return np.sqrt(((x2-x1)**2) - ((y2-y1)**2))

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')


vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('4pmeet.mp4')
success, image = vidcap.read()
count = 0
sec = 0
try:
    if not os.path.exists('all_frames'):
        os.makedirs('all_frames')
except OSError:
    print('Error: Creating directory of data')

gimg = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
facesBase = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(image, scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighbors=5)
fnum = 0

min_dist = 100000.0
numf = 0
fps = round(vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS), 0) - 1
ffc = 0 #count for max faces loop
result_array = np.empty((0, 5))
result_array1 = np.empty((0, 5))
while ffc / fps < 10: #loop to find max faces in the first 30 seconds
    gimg = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # gimg = np.array(gimg, dtype='uint8')
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(image, scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighbors=5)

    if len(faces) > numf:
        numf = len(faces)
        facesBase = faces

    success, image = vidcap.read()

    ffc += 1

fb = []
for fa in facesBase:
    print(fa)


while success:
    if count % fps < 1:
        time = round(vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC),0)

        for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
            print(faces)
            print(len(faces))
            crop_face = gimg[y-10:y + h+10, x-10:x + w +10]
            distance = 1000000
            for num, face in enumerate(facesBase, start=0):
                d = dist(x, facesBase[num][0], y, facesBase[num][1])
                if d < distance:
                    f = num
                    distance = d

            cv2.imwrite("./all_frames/frame%dPerson%d.jpg" % (count,f), crop_face)  # save frame as JPEG file
            # cv2.imshow("cropped", crop_face)
            print('Read a new frame: ', count, f, success, time, fps)
            # f += 1

            # if len(facesBase) < len(faces):
            #     facesBase = faces

    success, image = vidcap.read()

    count += 1


vidcap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```